# How to set reading permission for each separate page?

Tags: users

How to set reading permission for each separate page? 
Do already have existing drupal setting for us to use? or I need to coding it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module allows you to configure permissions by content type or, with some additional configuration, by node (per page).  It works on D6 and D7.

Comment: This module works great for us

Answer (score 0):

Modules like [Nodeaccess](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) and [Node access user reference](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) should give full access control over each node.